# Apache LocationMatch throws 500 and AddOutputFilterByType does nothing

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip

I need to add below directives to apache. But I get 500 when I add these lines.

```
<LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
# RFC says only cache for 1 year
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</LocationMatch>
```

Additionally response is not gzipped when I add:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript
```

Apache version is: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)

App: rails 3.2 app

When I checked response&request for gzip problem, I see that browser requested gzip:

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

but response not gzipped.

Comment: I solved gzip error, but I still cannot add LocationMatch directive in my htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it, 
LocationMatch directive on .htaccess files are not permitted.
see: [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#locationmatch)

So I placed these directives into my vhost in httpd.conf file, and now everything is great.

Comment: It would be nice if you add the directives to the answer.

Comment: @LucasKauffman sorry to mention about that. I didn't change directives, they are all same as my original question.  I just opened my httpd.conf file, and paste them in domain vhost section